# What is this macro define for?

Tags: c, macros, embedded, c-preprocessor, nxp-microcontroller

I am new in embedded code and I'm reading an example code of NXP, this example is written for FRDM-KL25Z. And in file main.h, I do not know the line:

```
#ifndef MAIN_H_
#define MAIN_H_

#endif /* MAIN_H_ */
```

is using for what? I think maybe it defines the name for main.h is MAIN_H_ ? But the purpose of this define is what? And in file `main.c`, it still `include main.h` as below:

```
#include "main.h"
```

Comment: It is not specific to embedded code, you need include guards in any C or C++ code.  Most modern compilers support #pragma once as an alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's imagine I have a header file like so:

```cpp
// foo.h
struct Foo
{
};
```

And then I accidentally include it twice:

```cpp
#include "foo.h"
#include "foo.h"
```

This would end up attempting to compile the following, which would generate an error...

```cpp
struct Foo
{
};
struct Foo //< error 'Foo' declared twice
{
};
```

One way to fix this is to get the pre-processor to remove the second occurance, and to do this we define a unique identifer per header file. e.g.

```cpp
#ifndef FOO_H_
#define FOO_H_
struct Foo
{
};
#endif
```

And now if we accidentally include it twice...

```cpp
#ifndef FOO_H_    //< not yet declared
#define FOO_H_    //< so declare it
struct Foo
{
};
#endif

#ifndef FOO_H_   //< this time FOO_H is defined... 
#define FOO_H_   //< ... so DO NOT include this code. 
struct Foo
{
};
#endif
```

Personally though I'd recommend achieving this same thing via the slighty non-standard (although supported by most, if not all, compilers).

```cpp
#pragma once   //< only ever include this file once
struct Foo 
{
};
```

Comment: thank you so much. Now i am unstanding the purpose of the pre-processor FOO_H_ is avoiding case i include file.h more than once. So in main.h, can i write include FOO_H_ instead of foo.h ?

Comment: Given the question is tagged C, examples in C++ are probably inappropriate.

Comment: @ThanhNguyen No, that make no sense.  This example is also rather simplistic.  The more likely scenario is where you have two _different_ include files that each nest-include a common header.

Comment: '#praga once’ ?  Typo.